# Openlayers - MapQuest

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers

We are using mapquest tiles(ol.source.MapQuest) in our application. But, mapquest team is discontinued to access their tiles from 11th July, is there any open source alternative to use instead of mapquest.

Comment: OpenStreetMap, or self hosted version of that. What have you actually looked at?

Comment: Thanks Brad for your prompt response.. Yes, we want to use OpenStreetMap..

Comment: What have you already looked at?

Comment: @BradHards, sorry, I didn't get you... can you please elaborate a bit..

Comment: We expect that you've at least looked at some web sites, used a web search, evaluated some options before you came here. If you didn't find anything suitable, why were they not suitable?

Answer (score 1):

There are various alternatives:

- The [tiles page in the OSM wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles) has a list of tile servers. Before choosing one make sure to read their tile usage policy / terms of use first.
- The [tile usage policy for the official OSM tile server](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_usage_policy) also lists some alternatives (currently Stamen, MapBox and CartoDB).
- There is also a list of [commercial OSM software and services](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Commercial_OSM_Software_and_Services).
- And of course you can just [run your own tile server](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/).

Comment: Could you please let me know the tiles used in this example http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenLayers .. I think it is from openlayers and it is opensource..  I want to ensure this example is not using any third party tiles like(bing, mapquest, google, etc...).

Comment: Most of these examples use tiles from OpenStreetMap. The tile server serving these tiles has a [tile usage policy](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_usage_policy). The data behind these tiles is "open source" (the data is licensed under ODbL). The tiles are licensed under CC BY-SA 2.0. Still you need to comply with the tile usage policy of this particular server since it costs resources (i.e. money) to run this server.